# What is an "Ni-Cr" battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I have encountered a few references to Ni-Cr batteries, such as a [Charger for NiMH and Ni-Cr batteries](http://charger.nitecore.com/CHARGER/i/i8/i8_EN_08/). I think it may be a synonym for NiCd. If you can shed any light on this, it would be most welcome. If it is just a synonym for NiCd, how did it come about?

I also found several alibaba listings for "NiCr" batteries. They appeared to just be NiCd, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think they are just typos - there is no such battery chemistry as Ni-Cr.

Comment: odd.. only battery reference I found was Structural and electrochemical properties of Nichrome anode thin films for lithium battery.. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10832-007-9405-y but that's not what ali-baba is selling

Comment: Ali-baba could be a typo. But the Nightcore charger, too?

Comment: It probably is just a typo. 'r' and 'd' are not that far apart on the keyboard. Should I delete the question? Or might it possibly help someone later?

Comment: "No" (with some explanation) is a perfectly good answer to a question. @KevinWhite Perhaps you could put what you said in that comment in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such battery called Ni-Cr. It is likely just a typo.

As other commenters have mentioned the 'r' and 'd' are close on the keyboard.

The only common nickel based battery chemistries are Ni-Cd (or Nickel Cadmium) or Ni-MH (Nickel Metal Hydride).  They operate similarly with Ni-MH being the more recent with better capacity and not using toxic Cadmium. They both have terminal voltages of ~1,2v which is similar to zinc-carbon (manganese alkaline) primary batteries.  They are relatively safe and do not usually suffer from explosive or thermal failure in the way that Li-Ion batteries do.

They both suffer from high self-discharge rates of many % per month and have been supplanted in modern equipment by Lithium based batteries (e.g. Li-Ion).

Comment: I actually contacted nitecore and they confirmed it is a mistake. At some point I guess they will fix the typo on their website.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Ni-Cr batteries" can be found only in conjunction with "Nitecore" producer of chargers and batteries. I would guess that this is a marketing ploy to promote the Nitecore brand, "Ni-core" batteries.